# How do we define convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Can we define convergence of a sequence in the set $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$?How do we define that?Do we require metric space for this convergence?

Comment: @Bungo Do the extended reals form a metric space "commonly used" metric space? If so, how is the distance function defined for $\infty$?

Comment: From Bungo's definition you can check $x \to atan(x)$ is an isomorphism of topological space $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\} \to [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ the latter being a metric space. When putting the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$ there is no $\pm \infty$ point because the distance between $0$ and $n$ is unbounded.

Comment: @Bungo, please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\in\Bbb R$ the definition of $x_n\to x$ is the same as in calculus. The definitions of $x_n\to\infty$ and $x_n\to-\infty$ are also the same as in calculus.

(Yes, that works even for $x_n\in\Bbb R\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$. For example, $x_n\to0$ means for every (real) $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $|x_n|<\epsilon$ for every $n>N$. If $x_3=\infty$ then $|x_n|\ge\epsilon$.)

Comment: You did not get my question,I meant that the sequence $(x_n)$ is in $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$

Comment: would you elaborate it in a separate answer(not as a comment),Do we actually use such sequences,suppose we define $M_n:=sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}{x^n}$ and consider the sequence ${M_n}$,then it is a sequence in extended reals.

Comment: because for $x>1$ the sequ. would diverge to $\infty$

Comment: @Kishalay Sarkar: The same definitions are used, but you need to extend the ordering on the reals so that for each real number $a$ we have $-\infty < a$ and $a < \infty$ (and other "grammar nit-picks", such as $\infty < \infty$ is false, $-\infty \leq -\infty$ is true, etc.). *(moments later)* Well, maybe a bit more is needed. One way is $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ if and only if (for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $x_n \in \mathbb R$ and $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ in the usual sense) OR (there exists a tail of $\{x_n\}$ each term of which is $\infty).$

Comment: I think this satisfies me.

Comment: Similarly for $x_n \rightarrow -\infty,$ and for $x_n \rightarrow a$ (where $a \in \mathbb R)$ this only holds when at most finitely many of the terms are infinite and a tail of the sequence converges to $a$ in the usual sense of convergence of real numbers.

Answer (score 4):

$\overline{\Bbb R}$, the extended reals, is a linearly ordered set and it gets the order topology: at the maximum $+\infty$ it has neighbourhoods of the form $(x, +\infty]$ (any $x < +\infty$ allowed but values $x=n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ suffice for a local base) and at the minumum $-\infty$ we have neighbourhoods $[-\infty, x)$ ($ x > -\infty$ but values of the form $x=-n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ suffice for a local base again) and all other $x$ have basic neighbourhoods of the form $(a,b)$ with $a < x < b$, as usual for the reals.

Knowing local bases, we also know convergence: for convergence within $\Bbb R$ this is the same as the usual notion, but $x_n \to \infty$ iff for each $K \in \Bbb R$, there exists some $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $x_n \ge K$. For $-\infty$ we have $x_n \le K$ instead.

We could give it a metric, as the space is (regular and) second countable (and order isomorphic to $[0,1]$) but we don't need to do so.

Comment: would you please elaborate as I am new in analysis(BSc 3rd sem) and have not studied metric space(which is in 4th sem) yet.I have worked with $\mathbb R$ only.

Comment: @Kishalay Sarkar: What you appear to want was given in David C. Ullrich's answer. Henno Brandsma's answer shows how to formalize that notion in various more advanced/general contexts.

Comment: I meant convergence of a (sequence in $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$.)not convergence of a sequence (in $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$.)