# Equivalent definitions of convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ and convergence in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

The usual metric space definition of convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ as a metric space is

(1) $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_{n}=x$ iff $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists N_{\epsilon}$ s.t. $n \geq N_{\epsilon} \implies |x-x_{n}| < \epsilon$.

Basically, this means that starting from some integer $N_{\epsilon}$ all elements of the sequence are in an open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $x$.

I want to show that this is equivalent to the topological definition of convergence for $\mathbb{R}$. Note that the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with the absolute value distance forms a topology since arbitrary unions and finite intersections of open sets are open.

The topological definition of convergence is

(2) $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_{n}=x$ iff for every open neighborhood $B$ of $x$ $\exists N_{B}$ s.t. $n \geq N_{B} \implies x_{n} \in B$.

An open neighbourhood of $x$ is any open set $U \in \tau$ s.t. $x \in U$.

It is easy to show that (1) $\implies$ (2). Consider an open set $A$ and let $x \in A$. Then by definition of open sets in a metric space, every point in $A$ is an interior point, i.e. $\exists$ some open ball $B_{r}(x)$ with $r>0$ that is completely contained in A. Thus, by (1) all points of the sequence $x_{n}$ will eventually lie in $B_{r}$ and thus in $A$. Since $A$ was arbitraty this proves the claim.

Similarly, we can show that (2) $\implies$ (1) since every neighborhood of $x$ of the topology $\tau$ is an open set which contains $x$. In particular, any open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ with $\epsilon>0$ is a neighborhood of $x$. This means that starting from some integer $N_{\epsilon}$ all elements of the sequence are contained in $B_{\epsilon}$ or in other words $\exists N_{\epsilon}$ s.t. $n \geq N_{\epsilon} \implies |x-x_{n}| < \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary (1) holds.

I've got a few questions about this.

1) Is my proof correct? I'm a bit worried about the proof for (2) $\implies$ (1).

2)It is easier to think of the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ as a topolocial space rather than a metric space. Now it would make sense if convergence of a seqence in $\mathbb{R} \implies$ convergence in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Is this true? What are the neighborhoods in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$? Are the neighborhoods simply the open sets, i.e. sets in the topology of the extended real line?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Regarding your second question, the answers and comments in the recent question [How do we define convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3324621/13130) might be helpful. Incidentally, I find it rather curious that these kinds of questions keep popping up, because pretty much any real or complex analysis text that introduces the extended real line and/or the extended complex plane discusses these things in a fair amount of detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course, there are lots of analysis texts that cover the extended real line, but this question came up while studying measure theory and I wondered whether some convergence theorems I know from real analysis still hold. Sine I have already had an idea, I thought it might be better to just prove it on my own.

Comment: Your statement of (2) should use $N_B$ instead of $N_{\epsilon}.$ Also, your proof of "limit exists according to (2)" implies "limit exists according to (1)" seems a bit hard to follow. (2) says that for every open neighborhood of $x,$ there is a tail of the sequence each term of which is in that neighborhood. As a special case, then, it follows that for every **open ball centered at** $x,$ there is a tail of the sequence each term of which is in that ball. Now notice that this is just (1) expressed in geometric language.

Comment: I agree that the proof is a bit short, but I have used exactly the same argument as you stated, namely that  (1) follows as a special case from (2). I will edit the proof later to make it a bit clearer. Your point about the definition of (2) is indeed a mistake since the N in this case depends on which ball B we consider. Thanks for the help.