# How is this version of Portmanteau theorem well-defined?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, metric-spaces, borel-measures

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal P(X)$ the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$. I'm reading below theorem in [this](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ekcraig/math/260L_S20/Lecture%206.pdf) lecture note.

> *Lemma 6.2.* Suppose $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2,\ldots \in \mathcal P(X)$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly. Then for any lower semicontinuous, bounded below $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup\{+\infty\}$,
> $$
> \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int g d \mu_{n} \geq \int g d \mu.
> $$

This result also appears as *Theorem A.3.11.* in Dupuis's textbook *A weak convergence approach to the theory of large deviations*.

---

For sure, the lower semicontinuous function $g$ is measurable, but not necessarily integrable. Take $x \mapsto e^x$ as an example. How can we take the limit
$$
\liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int g d \mu_{n}
$$
if there are some $g$ and $N$ such that
$$
\int g d \mu_{N} = +\infty?
$$

Comment: $g$ is bounded below. In measure theory such functions are not called integrable but $\int g d\mu$ still exists in $\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$.

Comment: @KurtG. Could you confirm if my following understanding of the convergence of a sequence in extended real line is correct? Assume that we have a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$. Let $I := \{n \mid a_n = +\infty\}$ and $F:=\{n \mid n\notin I\}$. If $I$ is finite, then $\liminf_n a_n := \liminf_{n\in F, n \to \infty} a_n$. If $I$ is infinite and $F$ is finite, then $\liminf_n a_n := +\infty$. If $I$ is infinite and $F$ is infinite, then $\liminf_n a_n := \min\{+\infty, \liminf_{n\in F, n \to \infty} a_n\}$.

Comment: Probably correct but much too complicated. We know that the liminf of *any* sequence in $\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$ is either finite or $+\infty$. This follows easily from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior#Definition_for_sequences) as the sequence $(\inf_{m\ge n}a_m)_n$ is increasing in $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KurtG. mentioned in a comment, the fact that $g:X \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ is l.s.c. and bounded from below ensures that $\int f \mathrm d \mu \in \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$. On the other hand, the convergence in $\mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ is well-defined with the order topology mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3324815/1019043) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3332949/1019043).